# How would you assign a RecyclerView object to a user favourite with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am fairly new to android development and Firestore as a whole, I have reached a hurdle in my project that I can't find much of a solution for, so I wondered if I could ask for some guidance.

I am making an android app where a user can follow or create their own hikes, so far I have the hiking routes themselves stored in firestore that populates a recyclerView, a user system using firebase Auth to register & log in etc, these are both in their own collections as shown below,

(I am unable to post images so I can only send links)
[Users collection](https://i.ibb.co/vvpRVBT/Screenshot-2021-09-10-at-13-46-36.png)
[Routes collection](https://i.ibb.co/W6nh1Z4/Screenshot-2021-09-10-at-13-46-49.png)

What I am wanting to achieve if possible to to be able to have user have a list of 'Favourite routes' Ideally thy can press a button on the recycler view that would save the route to their account as a favourite, I am just unsure how to approach this kind of implementation.

RecyclerView

```
public class RouteListerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    public RouteViewModel routeViewModel;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference routeRef = db.collection("Routes");
    private routeRvAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_lister);
        InitRecyclerView();
    }

    private void InitRecyclerView() {

        Query query = routeRef.orderBy("routeName", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Route> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Route>()
                .setQuery(query, Route.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new routeRvAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new routeRvAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {

                Route route = snapshot.toObject(Route.class);
                List<Point> listP = route.getRoutePoints();
                Intent intent = new Intent(RouteListerActivity.this, RouteActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("Route", route);

                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
                | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                adapter.deleteRoute(viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                Toast.makeText(RouteListerActivity.this, "Route Has Been Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Kindest regards!

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You  can add an Favourite_Routes Array type variable member in **users** Model/Data class/ Pojo class.

And for add items in **Favourite_Routes** Array create another Model/Data class/ Pojo class. Which is hold the data of favourite routes. or You can simple store **Route ID** in Favourite_Routes.

With saved route Ids you can implement **Query** for recycler view as you required.